# Will Google crawl content inside bootstrap tabs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-crawlers

I need to boostrap tabs in my website. Inside each tabs there are some links and content. I don't know if Google will crawl these links or not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

YES! Google bots crawl through each element and links and pages inside that links.

Comment: Care to share a relevant documentation page?

Comment: dude bots will not look at your divs and the styles that you applied for your divs or elements. it is only take care of your external links and relevant content.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/crawling-indexing/

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/the-way-google-scans/

Comment: to get an idea about bots and crawling.